# How to show particular div id on the page using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jsp

I want to show a particular div with particular id on the page. I am able to show the div with class information but when I try to access it by giving div id then it is not working, this is how am trying to access it from javascript.

```
if((document.getElementById("apMain.stageId").value) == "11"){
            doShow();
    }else{
      alert('else');
    }
    function doShow(){
            $(".bill_info").show();
      }
```

I want to access `div with id= stg_Pdel`, I have tried using

```
function doShow(){
        $('#stg_Pdel').show();
  }
```

but am not able to get the div open on the page, what should be the right approach of doing it ?

My div is:

```
<div class="bill_info">
<h3>Additional required fields</h3>
    <div id="stg_install">
        <div class="row">
            <span class="label">
                <form:label path="billingInfo.otc" cssClass="normalText" cssErrorClass="normalTextRed" >OTC:</form:label>
            </span>
            <span class="formw">
                <form:input path="billingInfo.otc" cssClass="normalField" cssErrorClass="validationError" size="25" disabled='true'/>
            </span>
            <span class="error">Values for all charge fields must be numeric.</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="stg_Pdel">
        <div class="row">
            <span class="label">
            <form:label path="billingInfo.priceId" cssClass="normalText" cssErrorClass="normalTextRed" >Price Type:</form:label>
            </span>
            <span class="formw">
                <form:select path="billingInfo.priceId" cssErrorClass="validationError" disabled='true'>
                    <form:options items="${priceTypes}" itemValue="key" itemLabel="value" />
                </form:select>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id='stg_closed'>
        <div class="row">
            <span class="label">
                <form:label path="billingInfo.billingClassId" cssClass="normalText" cssErrorClass="normalTextRed" >Billing:</form:label>
            </span>
            <span class="formw">
                <form:select path="billingInfo.billingClassId" cssErrorClass="validationError" disabled='true'>
                    <form:option value="" label="--Select--" />
                    <form:options items="${billingTypes}" itemValue="key" itemLabel="value" />
                </form:select>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you viewed source on the rendered page to verify jsp has not manipulated the element's Id? I do not know abut JSP, but the ASP.NET parser does.

Comment: @Rachel - I fixed the indentation of your HTML. Note that I didn't change any tags, but rather gave the existing ones proper indentation. You can now more easily see that `stg_Pdel` is a child of `stg_install` and not a sibling.

Comment: @Patrick: `stg_Pdel` is **NOT** child of `stg_install` but they both are child of `bill_info` class

Comment: @Rachel - You're **RIGHT**. I missed a tag. Notice that you have `</div></div>`. So the indentation still isn't quite right. (Looking back at the original code posted, I did have it right.)

Comment: Well it wasn't there originally ...

Comment: So how can I display of `div id ?`

Comment: Going back to the original code, I do see that I had it correct. So we should be using your edit? If so, could you please correct the indentation so we know what you're dealing with?

Comment: Ok. Let me edit it properly and re-post it.

Comment: I have re-edited it properly and so now there should not be any confusion and my question is `How can I display a div id using jquery ?`

Comment: Is there *any* possibility that you have another element on the page with the same ID `stg_Pdel`?

Comment: No I do not have any other div with similar id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a closing `</div>` tag right before that one, so it's inside the previous one ("stg_install"). An outer "display: none" will override (sort-of) the "display: block" (or whatever) on the inner `<div>`.

If it's not the `<div>` nesting issue that was present in the initial post of the question, then perhaps there's a hint of the problem where you mention showing the `<div>` with class "bill_info".  If that whole thing is currently not showing, then calling `.show()` on another `<div>` (the "stg_Pdel" `<div>`) will have no effect.  Again, the outer block will hide it no matter what it's "display" style is set to.

If the ".bill_info" `<div>` is hidden, you need to do something like this:

```
function doShow(stage) {
  $('.bill_info').show()
    .children('div').hide().end()
    .find('#' + stage).show();
}
```

You'd pass "doShow" either "stg_Pdel", "stg_install", or "stg_closed", and it would make sure one of those inner `<div>` elements is showing. *edit for more detail* — The idea is to do the following things:

1. Make sure that the over all "bill_info" block is visible;
2. Find the immediate child `<div>` elements and hide them all;
3. Find the target "stg" `<div>` and make it visible

Note that using `.find()` is not really necessary because you're searching by "id" value, but it should work.

If you need the function to work on more than one stage, you could do it like this:

```
function doShow() {
  $('.bill_info').show()
    .children('div').hide();

  for (var ac = 0; ac < arguments.length; ++ac) {
    var stg = arguments[ac];
    $('#' + stg).show();
  }
}
```

Comment: where am I missing `</div>` ?

Comment: @Pointy - Now that I look closer, there is an extra `</div>` toward the end. This may be a case of awkward indentation.

Comment: @Rachel - So `stg_Pdel ` is intended to be a child of `stg_install`?

Comment: `stg_Pdel` and `stg_install` they are both on same level and are child of `bill_info` class

Comment: @Rachel - Then @Pointy is overall correct. You currently have `stg_Pdel` as a child of `stg_install`. It just doesn't look like it because you reduced the indentation of the elements after `stg_install`. I'll correct the indentation in your question in a minute. It'll be easy to stop then.

Comment: i have corrected the indentation but that is not the issue coz in the code i am running, it was already there, somehow i missed it while writing the question and so there was this confusion but still am not able to print value of that div id.

Comment: @Rachel I've updated my answer.  Also, it would help a lot if you told us what you **do** see on your page.  Do you see the other "stg" `<div>` elements?

Comment: @Pointy: I do not see anything on the page if am trying to display particular `div id` but if I try to display `div class` then am able to see complete `fields` in that `div class`.

Comment: If the ".bill_info" `<div>` is currently hidden, then you **cannot** show the "stg_Pdel" `<div>` that is inside of it.

Comment: @Pointy - I think you nailed it (again).

Comment: @patrick dw I don't know this one may have some fight left in it yet

Comment: @Pointy: Its not fight, am just trying to understand that why am I not able to display div with id ?

Comment: @Rachel Oh I was just kidding :-)  I know you're not fighting!  You can display it, but you have to make sure that all of the parent containers are showing too

Comment: @Rachel - Pointy didn't mean a fight with you, but rather with the issue you're having in your code. :o)

Comment: @Rachel does ".bill_info" ever get hidden, or not?  It's hard to tell from what you have posted.

Comment: Initially `.bill_info` is hidden and when change in value of one field box, that class div is active, also I have meeting in 10 mins for 3hrs and so wont be able to discuss further, kindly visit this question after 3 hrs from now.

Comment: @patrick: oh ok then its fine, even am fighting the issue at hand.

Comment: @Rachel - In CSS do: `.bill_info {display:none;} bill_info > div {display:none;}`. Then to show, do: `$('#stg_Pdel').show().parent().show();`

Comment: i will try this once am back from the meeting.

Comment: `$('#stg_Pdel').show().parent().show();`, this i should be doing inside the js call right ?

Comment: @Pointy: I see your updated answer and this approach works for me but now let's say I want to open multiple div Ids than can I do that using `doShow('stg_Pdel','stg_install')` 
?

Comment: @Rachel yes you could do that - the function would have to iterate through the `arguments` object. It should hide all the children first and then un-hide each "id" in the list

Comment: can you give an exmaple for this Pointy as I am not that familiar with css and js and would appreciate it.

Comment: +1 for all your guidance and also please explain me actually what is happening in your provided code as I want to understand as to what is happening in there.

Comment: Thank you Pointy and appreciate your coming back to this question :)